# Pandas df - Converting categorical data to numeric data Also converting column name into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is how my data frame looks like, where left and right are 2 columns, Data in column can be comma separated. If a row contains values in right column, then left will be `NAN`
Total **6** distinct values.**(a-f)**

[image: Existing df]

I want this data to be transformed into, Column name is also transformed into new columns based on values. I can use get `get_dummies()` to convert column values into Boolean value, but not sure how to convert column name into multiple columns.

[image]

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'Right': ['a;b;c', ''], 'Left': ['', 'c;e;d']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

plz provide input in text, not image.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'id': [1, 2], 'Right': ['a;b;c', None], 'Left': [None, 'c;e;d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df

```
    id  Right   Left
0   1   a;b;c   None
1   2   None    c;e;d
```

---

**Code**

```
tmp = df.set_index('id').stack().str.get_dummies(';').reset_index().melt(['level_1', 'id'])
tmp = tmp[tmp['value'].eq(1)].assign(pos=tmp['variable'].add('_pos'))
out = pd.concat([tmp.pivot(index='id', columns='variable', values='value'), 
                 tmp.pivot(index='id', columns='pos', values='level_1')], axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
cats = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
cols = sum([[i, i + '_pos'] for i in cats], [])
out = out.reindex(cols, axis=1)
```

out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) on each target column in a custom function, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
def to_dummies(s):
    tmp = s.str.get_dummies(';').replace({0: np.nan})
    return tmp.join(tmp.replace({1: s.name})
                       .add_suffix('_pos')
                    )

cols = ['Right', 'Left']

out = (pd.concat([to_dummies(df[c]) for c in cols])
         .groupby(level=0).first()
         .sort_index(axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
     a  a_pos    b  b_pos    c  c_pos    d d_pos    e e_pos
0  1.0  Right  1.0  Right  1.0  Right  NaN  None  NaN  None
1  NaN   None  NaN   None  1.0   Left  1.0  Left  1.0  Left
```